# Adding description to files for easy remembering

Tags: files, filemanager, navigation

I have a big amount of files on my laptop, and just the names are not enough for me to remember what each one does.

Basically, is there any way to add a description to each file without having to open them one by one?
I have one or two source codes being added up daily, so this would be extremely helpful.

**EDIT**
I made a mistake by not being explicit enough, I will try to clear it up:

I have multiple code files each for a different problem, and usually in different languages and in multiple versions. My folders hierarchy is pretty neat, but it is a hassle for the CLI.

A tagging method, with a search capability would be very helpful.

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: 11.10 with openbox installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Emblems in Nautilus

Right click a file/folder and go to its properties. You can add remove emblems and even change the icon itself. That should help you differentiate between files and give you a way to tag files.

---

A better alternative, which I found via [one thing well](http://onethingwell.org/post/17212029813) is tmsu :

## [tmsu](http://www.tmsu.org/)

> tmsu is an application that allows you to organise your files by associating them with tags. It provides a tool for managing these tags and a virtual file- system to allow tag based access to your files.

#### Tagging

```
tmsu tag summer.mp3 music big-jazz mp3 #tmsu [files] [tag]
tmsu tag --tags "music mp3" *.mp3 #filenames at last
tmsu merge umsic music #merge two tags
```

#### Listing

```
tmsu tags #lists tags
tmsu files mp3 -classical -rock #remove some tags
```

tmsu also creates a virtual file system, which uses symlinks to files. Directories inside this mount will refer to the tags themselves.

### Installation

Download the latest version from [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/oniony/tmsu/downloads) and extract it somewhere. Copy the `bin/tmsu` file to a folder that is in your path (such as `/bin/` or `~/bin`).

Comment: I have tried this before, but I mostly use the command-line to navigate through files and folders. And usually the description is long enough to be covered by an emblem.

Comment: @cameleon I've updated my answer to include tmsu, please try it out.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've been trying different tag-based file-systems, but this virtual one is doing the trick. Sorry for the long delay though

Answer (score 0):

Folders and Symlinks.

```
/photos/by-date/2012/01/31/picture1234.jpeg -> /photos/all/picture1234.jpeg
/photos/by-person/mom/picture1234.jpeg -> /photos/all/picture1234.jpeg
/photos/by-event/birthdays/by-person/mom/picture1234.jpeg -> /photos/all/picture1234.jpeg
```

This is a commonly used paradigm. One that comes to mind is `/dev/disk/*`

Comment: You can use alt+drag in the file browser to create sym-links.